# Getting 0 or 1 as probability values in neural network Keras sequential model

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, sequential

I am running my training set of 30k on python library Keras for neural network (model "sequential").

When i am fitting the model and calculating probabilities on the test set (size = 13k) then I am getting 0 or 1 only. Whereas I am supposed to get some fractional values like 0.62, 0.42, 0.31 etc.

I tried using class_weight and setting it to 'auto' or 'balanced' but I was not able to solve this issue.

Output is not integer type, its float type only.

Below is the code

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
seed = 8 
np.random.seed(seed)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(9, input_dim=8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

from keras.optimizers import SGD
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True), metrics=['accuracy'])

trainx = X_train.as_matrix()
trainy = y_train.as_matrix()

import time as time
start = time.time()
model.fit(trainx, trainy, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=10, verbose = 2,    class_weight ='auto')
print (time.time() - start)

X_test = X_test.as_matrix()
y_test = y_test.as_matrix()

proba = model.predict_proba(X_test, batch_size=10)
```

And the values of proba are all 0s.
The data has only 2% defaulter cases, so its imbalanced class.

Comment: Would you please show us your code here , we can help you better then.

Comment: Start with examining input to the final layer. Softmax can yield one-hot like output if weights have large magnitude.

Comment: Have you try to use `model.predict()` instead? Also it would be helpful if you can gives us sample of the dataset as sometimes the problem lies there (eg. normalization issue)

Comment: Downvoted for adding urgent begging back in after it was explicitly taken out. Please do not attempt to transfer your own deadlines onto volunteers, it is not polite. If you are merely overwriting edits to your question by accident, please always refresh the page before editing, so that any amendments made by volunteer editors are preserved.

Comment: What is your model's accuracy? could it simply be so overfitting as to always take the binary result?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds awfully like that you might be getting an integer return, which can only be 1 or 0, and not a float return. Thus you could try seeing whether `int` is in your code anywhere turning it into an integer, or you might need to turn it into a `float` somewhere. Impossible to tell without more context...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am wrong but I have never seen this argument to fit so far :

```
 class_weight ='auto'
```

I would try instead

```
class_weight = {0: 1., 1: 50.}
```

Indeed your problem seems to be coming from inbalanced dataset.